# Extract sections of PDF

Tags: pdf

I am trying to extract sections of a PDF file, for use in text analysis. I tried using [pdfextract](https://github.com/CrossRef/pdfextract) to accomplish this. However, a command such as

```
pdf-extract extract --regions --no-lines Bauer2010.pdf
```

only extract the `(x,y)` coordinates of a region, as in the example below.

```
<region x="226.32" y="750.47" width="165.57" height="6.37"
line_height="6.37" font="BGBFHO+AdvP4DF60E">Patient Education and
Counseling 79 (2010) 315-319</region>
```

Can sections of a PDF be extracted?

Comment: You probably should make clear what you mean by "sections of a PDF"?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://text-analyzer.com where you can upload your PDF file and it will convert it into a format suitable for Natural Language Processing.  Once converted into a text file it can then process the file, breaking it down into sentences with sentiment analysis.  It has over 40 different types of sentence views where you can tag sections.  Those tagged sentences can be exported.